# Minitest mocking Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, mocking, sinatra, minitest

I have Sinatra app inherited from `Sinatra::Base` class. In this app I have one helper method which I use in before filter. How to mock such method in tests using minitest mock library?

```
before do
  unless valid_signature?
    halt 401
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `valid_signature?` to be a Sinatra helper method, it needs to be part of a module. So assuming your module is `MyModule`

```
module MyModule
  def valid_signature?
  end
end
```

We can mock `valid_signature?` using minitest as follows:

```
MyModule.stub :valid_signature?, "stub return value" do
  # method is stubbed only in this block, so run tests from here
  # make sure your module was defined before you stub it.
end
```

If running your tests from within a block is too limiting, I would recommend looking at [Mocha stubbing and mock library](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) or simply manually redefining the method at runtime yourself in your test file:

```
MyModule
  def valid_signature?
    # you can only redefine after class has already been defined.
    "stub return value"
  end
end
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. I get "undefined method `valid_signature? for MyModule" error. Switching to mocha is not an option I think - this project has already quite a lot tests with minitest used.

Comment: Are you sure you replaced MyModule with your actual module name? You also need to make sure your module has been required first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your function defined as instance functions or in helpers block (which is practically the same thing) you can mock them with minitest like this:

```
def app
    MyApp.new
end

def test_valid_signature
    app.helpers.stub(:valid_signature?, @mock) do
        return true
    end
    # do something...
    assert valid_signature?
end
```